# UIsearchbar results to display viewcontollers rather than images

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Good afternoon all.

I have a question about the results generated by a uisearchbar and uitableviewcontoller.

At the moment I have it set up that the results generated display an image, but is it possible for the search result to be a specific viewcontroller? Ie you would essentially be searching through view controllers.

Im not sure if this is a stupid question but I searched on here and on google and found no answers!

Anyway, thanks for any help.
Mark

Comment: Can you explain? Why you need viewcontrollers as search results in tableview?

Comment: Well I want to be able to provide a search function that could search the entire app effectively . The app displays information on drugs, with the drugs divided into their therapeutic sections. So upon searching for a drug name it could display the view controller that contains the drug

Comment: Why not a cell that contains image-text related to the drug. And a segue to drug details view controller?